# How to search an entity list?

Tags: entity, resourceobject

I'm using the Wolfram `General Topology EntityStore`. From it, how would I search `EntityList["GeneralTopologyTheorem"]` to find, for example, those entities in the list that include the word "compact" in their name.

Here's where I am:

```
   obj = ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"];
   store = ResourceData[obj];
   data = EntityRegister[store]
(* {"GeneralTopologyConcept", "GeneralTopologyTheorem"} *)
   thms = EntityList["GeneralTopologyTheorem"]
```

The output from the last statement is a list of entites which display as "boxes" labeled with such things as "metric implies Hausdorff".

How do I search the list to find, say, which of those theorems in the store concern being compactt?

My notion is to somehow convert all the labels on those boxes into text and search the list of such texts. But how do I make that conversion? Or is there some better way?

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in response to my same question at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1902474. Namely:

```
EntityList["GeneralTopologyTheorem"] // CanonicalName //
  Select[StringContainsQ[#, "compact", IgnoreCase -> True] &]
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of the // Postfix? Is this acting like a Map?

Comment: @DougKimzey: In general, the postfix syntax `epr // func` means the same thing as `func[expr]`. So it would *not* act like `Map` unless `func` is listable.